# how to pass a list between pages xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.forms

I have a list of objects that should be passed to another view but I don't know how I can do that in Xamarin.forms, I think I should to use setBinding, but its the only thing I say in this case.
Thank you.

```
List<Localizacao> localizacaoList = new List<Localizacao>(); ;
        if (localizacao != null && lojaPerto != null)
        {
            localizacaoList = new List<Localizacao>();
            Localizacao loc = new Localizacao();
            loc.latitude = Double.Parse(lojaPerto.latitude);
            loc.longitude = Double.Parse(lojaPerto.longitude);
            localizacaoList.Add(loc);
            localizacaoList.Add(localizacao);
        }

        var secondPage = new Views.ComoChegarView ();
        secondPage.BindingContext = localizacaoList;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(secondPage);
```

In fact, I sent, but I can't get it again in the other view

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any additional framework, maybe you can try using constructor parameters.

```
public partial class ComoChegarView
{
   ...
   private List<Localizacao> Locals{get;set;}       

   public ComoChegarView(List<Localizacao> locals)
   {
      InitializeComponent(); //standard code that mix xaml and code behind
      this.Locals = locals; //store the data in property
      this.BindingContext = this; //Set the binding context
   }

}
```

So you can pass the value when you construct the page.

```
List<Localizacao> localizacaoList = new List<Localizacao>(); ;
if (localizacao != null && lojaPerto != null)
{
    localizacaoList = new List<Localizacao>();
    Localizacao loc = new Localizacao();
    loc.latitude = Double.Parse(lojaPerto.latitude);
    loc.longitude = Double.Parse(lojaPerto.longitude);
    localizacaoList.Add(loc);
    localizacaoList.Add(localizacao);
}

var secondPage = new Views.ComoChegarView (localizacaoList);
await Navigation.PushAsync(secondPage);
```

> **Remember that update your binding in XAML to reflect property access (for example)**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Locals}">...</ListView>
```

Comment: I can't do that...I can with string, int class...etc...but with my class Localizacao, or  other that I created, an error appears...but thank you

Comment: inconsistent acessibility; parameter type is less accessible than method

Comment: make your class public

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is perfectly supported by all serious MVVM libraries.
1) a view do not pass anything to another view, it is the job of the ViewModels
2) in a MVVM context you can use many techniques to send ou pass data from one ViewModel to another, the main being : MVVM messenger (there's one include in Xamarin.Forms) or dependency injection in the the ViewModel constructor (using an IoC container what most MVVM libraries are offering, using Unity, DryIoc, ...).
It is certainly hard to do if you do not master MVVM pattern but you should take a little time to study this pattern and some libraries as Prism. You will quickly see the benefit of such an approach and will be very happy to write code more efficiently (and find in a minute quick and clean solutions to problems like the one you're talking about here).